# Double ListView In FrameLayout Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-framelayout

I have one Drawerlayout when i start app, data into MainActivity with pagemain_layout(frame_container)... Everything is fine. But when i click item in drawerlayout appear double listview in pagemain_layout.

Pls... Give me a solution or edit my code.

Thank you very much !

Code MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mListDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    NavDrawerItemsAdapter adapterTest;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    ListView lvItemLayoutMain;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<String> mListTitle;
    ArrayList<String> mListURL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pagemain_layout);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        List<Integer> mListHeader = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        mListHeader.add(0);
        mListHeader.add(5);
        adapterTest = new NavDrawerItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                NavigationListItem.getListItemAdapter(this, mListHeader));
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mListDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
        lvItemLayoutMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item_main);
        mListDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
        mListDrawer.setAdapter(adapterTest);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        new LoadData().execute();
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayView(0);
        }

    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new HotNewsFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FocusNewsFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new EducationInfoFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new WorkingStudentsFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new TimeTableFragment();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new NoteFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mListDrawer.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mListDrawer.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mListDrawer);
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Vector<ArrayList<String>>> {
        String Url = "http://ued.vn/rss/cong-tac-sinh-vien.rss";
        Vector<ArrayList<String>> data = new Vector<ArrayList<String>>();
        final String KEYGROUP = "Thông báo";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
            mListTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
            mListURL = new ArrayList<String>();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Vector<ArrayList<String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            data = Utils.getDataNews(Url, KEYGROUP);
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Vector<ArrayList<String>> result) {
            if (data != null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                mListTitle = data.get(0);
                NewsHotAdapter adapter = new NewsHotAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.item_layout, mListTitle);
                lvItemLayoutMain.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

And Code In pagemain_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Problem Here !

[image: problem here]

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `android:layout_gravity="start"` defined in Listview of FrameLayout in xml. Your code should be as follows,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Try this code and let me know.

Comment: refer this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Oke... if i test success. i will accept your answer. But don't work ! I think fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit(); 
has problem